# SQL query to filter for 10+ million values

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create a daily chart/report that needs to count the number of rows per day, however has to filter for 10+ million values. Writing a where clause for this seems improbable as I will not be able to filter on millions of values.

Is there a way to do this using a query or does this filtration have to be done upstream during the ETL process before the data/rows are available and loaded into the DB each day?

Comment: "Writing a where clause for this seems improbable as I will not be able to filter on millions of values."

Have you tried though? More context would be useful to help answer this question--how is the database being used? Is it constantly being read so that you don't want to lock reads on the table for a certain period of time? If not it should be OK.

Comment: Hey @johnheroy - Here is a more detailed description:
1. Each day, millions of rows get added to one of our "transaction" tables. There could be more than 1 row per user each day/hour.
2. One of the unique parameters/columns here is IP address. We have millions of IP addresses each day that are sent as event parameters and loaded into our tables.
3. I need to filter out 10+ million IP addresses and report only on data limited to these IP's. 
4. Don't think I can stricture a where clause with 10+ million IP's through my SQL client.

Comment: You need to supply an example of what you mean by "filter on millions of values". Do you mean an `IN(...)` predicate with millions of items in the predicate? Perhaps you need to load those items into a temporary table and do a join instead.

Comment: @BillKarwin - That is correct. I do mean IN(...) where there would be 10+ million items in the predicate. I do agree that loading those items into a temp table would be great. I was looking to see if there was another way to accomplish that? Not sure how would I create a temp table without using the IN(...) predicate.

Comment: You have tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:snowflake]. I'm familiar with mysql, but not snowflake. It's likely that the query optimization techniques in snowflake will be different.

Comment: What @BillKarwin said - just put the values in a separate table and use a join.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a field with the date created (as a date type not a timestamp).  Create an index on this field, and go ahead and use a where clause.  This will allow the database to optimally filter by date.  Some databases will even keep track of the number of records matching a given key.  Doing this, is just using the where clause, and relying on the optimization of the implementation of your DBMS.